# How to Match with Regex "shortest match" in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm facing a problem with Regex... I had to match sharepoint URL.. I need to match the "shortest"

Something like:

```
http://aaaaaa/sites/aaaa/aaaaaa/

m = Regex.Match(URL, ".+/sites/.+/");
```

m.Value equals to the whole string...

How can I make it match

```
http://aaaaaaa/sites/aaaa/
```

and nothing else??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`.+` is greedy, so it will match as many characters as possible before stopping.  Change it to `.+?` and the match will end as soon as possible:

```
m = Regex.Match(URL, ".+/sites/.+?/");
```

Answer (score 8):

Try making the regex matching everything but a `/` instead of simply everything.  This is done by using the not form of the character class atom `[^]`.

```
m = Regex.Match(URL, ".+/sites/[^/]+/");
```

Comment: this still matches everything, you need to make it lazy i think `.+/sites/[^/]+?/`

Comment: +1 you're right, i think it was a copy paste error on my part when i tested it first time (and clearly a lack of understanding to boot)