# C# Read Multiple Tags in a string

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to allow user so they can read more than one tag in a string. So far, user could only add one tag

```
 if (rtb.Text.Contains("[b]"))
     {
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[b\](.*)\[/b\]");
       var v = regex.Match(rtb.Text);
       string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();

       rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Text.IndexOf("[b]");
       rtb.SelectionLength = s.Length + 7;

       rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font.FontFamily, rtb.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
       rtb.SelectedText = s;
     }


 else if (rtb.Text.Contains("[i]"))
     {
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[i\](.*)\[/i\]");
       var v = regex.Match(rtb.Text);
       string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();

       rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Text.IndexOf("[b]");
       rtb.SelectionLength = s.Length + 7;

       rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font.FontFamily, rtb.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic);
       rtb.SelectedText = s;
      }

richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = rtb.Rtf;
```

If i have this string:

```
"Hello [b]World[/b] Meet the [b]Programmer[/b]"
```

the output would be like this:

> "Hello **World Meet the Programmer**"

And if i have this string:

```
"Hello [b]World[/b] Meet the [i]Programmer[/i]"
```

the output would be like this:

> "Hello **World** Meet the [i]Programmer[/i]"

How to read multiple tags from a string? like, in a string if i have 2 [b][/b] tags, 5 [i][/i] tags or even mixed tags ([b][i][/i][/b])?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

**1. Greedy matching semantics of Regex**

`\[b\](.*)\[/b\]` looks for the **longest** possible match within your string, i.e. it is **greedy**. In your example, you expect it to match `[b]World[/b]`, when in fact it matches `[b]World[/b] Meet the [b]Programmer[/b]` (consequently making "Meet the" bold as well). This can easily be resolved using **non-greedy** syntax: `\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]` (note the extra `?`)

Details: [How to Match with Regex "shortest match" in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093489/how-to-match-with-regex-shortest-match-in-net)

**2. You are only looking for one occurrence of tags!**

Obviously, your code will only highlight a single `[b]`/`[i]` tag. Don't use `else if` if you want `[i]` to be handled if your string contains `[b]`. Use loops and `Regex.Matches` if you want to handle all occurrences of your regular expression instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex but still must be adapted slightly.

The test:

```
[Test]
public void Text()
{
        string str = "[b]Hello[/b] This is sample text [b] Goodbye [/b]";
        var bold = AllIndexesOf(str, "b").ToArray();
        
        // Assume the IEnumerable is even else it should of thrown an error
        for (int i = 0; i < bold.Count(); i += 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Pair: {bold[i]} | {bold[i+1]}");
        }

        // str.AllIndexesOf
}
```

Here is the method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Courtesy of : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24016130/5282506
    /// Adapted by me.
    /// 
    /// Pass in the unique symbol and itll find the first and last index pairs
    /// Can adapt to find all unique pairs at once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">The string.</param>
    /// <param name="searchstring">The searchstring letter (b, i, etc)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(string str, string searchstring)
{
    //assumes the string is formatted correctly. Only one tag of the same type inside each tag.

    int minIndex = str.IndexOf("["+searchstring+"]");
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First: {0}", minIndex);
        yield return minIndex;
        var maxIndexEnd = str.IndexOf("[/"+ searchstring +"]", minIndex + searchstring.Length +3);//added three for the [/ and ] characters.
        Console.WriteLine("End: {0}", maxIndexEnd);

        if (maxIndexEnd == -1)
        {
            //Malformed string, no end element for a found start element
            //Do something...
            throw new FormatException("Malformed string");
        }
        yield return maxIndexEnd;
        minIndex = str.IndexOf("[" + searchstring+"]", maxIndexEnd + searchstring.Length+2);//added two for the [ and ] characters
    }
}
```

If you wish to make it an extension method for string change signature to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string searchstring)
```

Heres the console result for bold indexes:

> Pair: 0 | 8
>
> Pair: 33 | 45

I have not fully tested this method for all edge cases.